# where is the breadcrumb printed at in the omega kickstart theme?

Tags: theming, breadcrumbs

can someone tell me where omega kickstart breadcrumb is printed in code I have looked in the templates dir and there dosent seem to be a page.tpl.php and the template.tpl.php in the main dir dosent have it either I want to move it to just over the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it's printed in in the `omega/templates/zone--content.tpl.php` template file in the Omega theme itself.

```
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
  <div id="breadcrumb" class="grid-<?php print $columns; ?>"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I typically copy in the default templates from the alpha/templates and omega/templates (in that order, there is some overlap) into my subtheme so I can find things.